Keyboard shortcuts not working in some documents
Good afternoon,
The 2x keyboards shortcuts that I use all the time are now only working in some documents and not others.
Highlight= Control +Alt H
Copy format = Control + shift +C
Paste Format = Control + shift + V
I have reset all my shortcuts in customize keyboards but I'm still having the same problem.
Any ideas why?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is the language of these files different from other documents?

Is 2x a keyboard macro utility, or a keyboard brand?
